# Get the link to your app before publishing it

Tags: android

Hi there I just finished my first app for Android that I want to publish. In my app I have a button which allows users to share the link, to my app in the Google Play Store. Now I don't know how to get that link, because my app isn't published yet. Thanks.

Comment: The link for your app in Google Play is like this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=#PACKAGE_NAME#

Comment: It's fully explained in [Linking to Your Products](https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html)

Answer (score 2):

the right practice is to call the view intent by market schema using your package name like below:

```
String yourPackageName = getPackageName();
try {
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + yourPackageName)));
} 
catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + yourPackageName)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the app's package name which is declared in manifest file.You can link your app -

**From an Android app:-**

```
market://details?id=<package_name>
```

**From a web site-**

```
http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>
```